# Can PowerQuery append rows based on columns?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I have a Dataset where the monthly volume's values per Model is shown in multiple columns instead of one. I.E:

Model        Jan    Feb    Mar     Apr    May

```
 A        5     12     26      56     23
```

Is it possible through PowerBI's PowerQuery to create one "Month" column where its values are being appended? Example:

Model   Month Volume

```
 A         Jan        5

 A         Feb       12

 A         Mar       26

 A         Apr        56

 A         May       23
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right click first column header and choose Unpivot other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'Unpivot columns', in the transform options of the query editor

[image]

Select the columns you want, then Unpivot.
You should give you this:

[image]

It will name the new columns Attribute and Value, you can then rename them to what you want. FYI when the next month (Jun) is added to the source it should unpivot that column automatically.

Comment: Thanks, this is was I needed.